# reloadData VS. reloadRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My question is as the title suggests. There's a difference between the two methods on iOS 7/iPhone 4.
The thing is I'm loading chat conversation in a bubble chat form. Each cell is a bubble containing the text msg, the date and the msg status (sent, received, seen or incoming).

When I need to reload a specific cell, I use the method `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` method. It works just perfect on iOS 8 (iPhone 4s and iPhone 5c). However, it does not on iOS 7 (iPhone 4). By "work" I mean it reloads just ok. But with the iOS 7 case, it only loads the background view without loading the text or any other elements.

Obviously, this means the data upon reloading is find (because it did work on other devices). I need to use `reloadData` after `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` to get the whole thing loaded in iOS 7 (iPhone 4). Or, I should scroll the table view to get the cell loaded.

I did work the problem out. But I want to know if that's a known bug in iPhone 4 (iOS 7).

Here's a piece of the code that might be helpful understanding the problem:

```
- (void)tableView:(UIBubbleTableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [self.bubbleTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[UIBubbleTableViewCell class]] && isEditing) {
        NSBubbleData * bubble;
        // fetch the corresponding bubble index in the bubble data array
        int bubbleIndex = [self getArrayIndexForIndexPath:indexPath];
        bubble = [self.bubbleData objectAtIndex:bubbleIndex];
        // making sure it's either a msg sent by me or msg sent by someone else. In other words, making sure it's neither a system message nor is it a header date or something.
        if (bubble.type != BubbleTypeMine && bubble.type != BubbleTypeSomeoneElse)
            return;

        // configure the bubble to be [de]selected
        bubble.isSelected = !bubble.isSelected;

        // add the Key-Value pair to the dictionary
        if ([selectedIndices valueForKey:bubble.msgID]) [selectedIndices removeObjectForKey:bubble.msgID];
        else [selectedIndices setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:bubbleIndex] forKey:bubble.msgID];

        // update gui
        [self.bubbleTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
        if([[self machineName] isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"] ||
           [[self machineName] isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"] ||
           [[self machineName] isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"]) { // iphone 4
            [self.bubbleTable reloadData];
        }
#if DEBUG
        printf("Selected Message Text: %s\n", [[[_anasDb getFromChatRoom:self.contactInternationalPhone message:bubble.msgID] valueForKey:MESSAGE_TEXT] UTF8String]);
#endif
    }
}
```

Clearly, you don't have to get every bit of it. Here's what the code is saying (in the context of the question):

1. Fetch instance of the cell.
2. Edit some of its properties so it would behave differently after next reloading
3. Reload that particular cell using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`- which works on every device so far except iPhone 4 (iOS 7) which needs `reloadData`.

Here's the relevant part of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIBubbleTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    NSBubbleData *data = [[self.bubbleSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];

    if (cell == nil) cell = [[UIBubbleTableViewCell alloc] init];

    cell.data = data;
    cell.showAvatar = self.showAvatars;
    if (data.isSelected) {
        cell.dim = YES;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.39 blue:0.106 alpha:0.2f];
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return cell;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a good practice to review your own code before searching for bugs in the OS. Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. But actually, I have reviewed the code couple times and I did find that there are others out there faced the same problem. None of them got a solid answer though. Some of them worked it out the same way I did (using the device model to decide) and the others just used `reloadData`.

That would be lots of lines of code if you are asking to post the code in question. I do realize the importance of posting the code, but that would be more than 4 classes! I'll try simplifying the code and edit the post with it in a sec.

Comment: I use both as a precautionary myself. I cannot explain why, this is a good question.

Comment: Can you also include your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method (or at least the most relevant parts of your cells' setup)? It's hard to tell what might be wrong looking at the code you have posted so far.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Will edit the post in a sec.

Comment: What does UIBubbleTableViewCell look like? Depending on where you're setting up the cell content, it might not be updating the content correctly when you grab a cell with `dequeueReuseableCellWithIdentifier:`. The only reason I can thing why this would be different between iOS 7 and iOS 8 is if something changed in the way UITableView works with UITableViewCell.

Comment: @JordanBondo, the data hasn't changed. As I have mentioned in the original post, the only change I made are some edits to cell properties to behave differently! The data itself that populates the cell is in a separate data structure, `NSBubbleData`. I have checked that the data is loaded in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 2):

Problem with your code is that u need load data to cell inside

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Inside `- (void)tableView:(UIBubbleTableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` adjust your data then call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` for specified rows. Do not change cell labels inside that method (or u can change both data and cell content here if u don't want to reload specific rows)

Reload data reloads all rows which is not what u need in most cases as it stops scrolling and recomputes heights, sections count, etc

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to say!

Comment: try changing background color for cell contentView instead of just cell

Comment: I am changing the background color of the cell. Check the original post!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with beginUpdates and endUpdates ?

```
[self.bubbleTable beginUpdates];
[self.bubbleTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
[self.bubbleTable endUpdates];
```

Comment: Yep. Makes no difference. Also, I confirmed that the problem isn't with the height method of the cell, in case you wonder. The cell is visible but the __some__ of the content isn't showing!